# Type of const (++) in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand the type of the expression const `(++)` in Haskell. I know the individual types of `const` and `(++)` and I know that you can leave out parameters in order to return partially applied functions.

If I type `:t const (++)` I get `const (++) :: b -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`. The way I think is that `(++)` wants two lists (I know however that all functions in Haskell are curried functions that actually just take one argument) and returns a list. This list is then the first argument to the `const` function, which waits for one more argument. So, I thought the type would be `const (++) :: [a] -> [a] -> b -> [a].`

But for example: `const (++) 1 "hello" "you"` returns `"helloyou"`. How come the thing that is returned from the `const` operation is not the first argument, according to the definition of `const` which is `const x _ = x`? Where in my thought process am I incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How come the thing that is returned from the const operation is not the first argument

It is. The first argument to `const` is `(++)`. So the result of the operation `const (++) 1` is in fact `(++)`, which is the first argument. So `const (++) 1` is `(++)`, meaning `const (++) 1 "hello" "you"` is `(++) "hello" "you"` and that is `"helloyou"`.

Comment: *and*, `const (++) 1 "hello" "you"` is the same as `(((const (++)) 1) "hello") "you"` is the same as `((const (++) 1) "hello") "you"` is the same as `( (++) "hello") "you"` is the same is `(++) "hello" "you"` which is `"hello" ++ "you"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
      ≡ ([a] -> [a] -> [a])

const :: c -> b -> c
```

Now, in `const (++)`, you want to give `(++)` as an argument to `const`. The argument to `const` should have type `c`, so you unify that with the type of `(++)`

```
     c  ~  ([a] -> [a] -> [a])
```

and get the specialised version

```
const :: ([a] -> [a] -> [a]) -> b -> ([a] -> [a] -> [a])
```

If that looks confusing, consider the simpler case of `const 1`. If the `1` has type `Int`, then we must have `c ~ Int` and in that case

```
const :: Int -> b -> Int
```

Because function arrows are right-associative, the `(++)`-specialisation can also be written

```
const :: ([a] -> [a] -> [a]) -> b -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Now if you actually apply that to `(++)`, you saturate the function argument and end up with

```
const (++) :: b -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```